# Pull to Refresh for WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to implemented a Pull to Refresh feature to reload pages within a WebView (Version 2.2 and above)?

Comment: Hi Alexander, can you please accept an answer if you think one of them solved your problem? ;-)

Comment: Hi alexander, could you tell us how you did it? What did you do with that library in order to get it working?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is possible. A very simple and to the point implementation for the same: 
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swipe-to-refresh/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

According to the documentation it also has support for WebViews and the demo app works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

This is now super easy by using the SwipeRefreshLayout. A good tutorial is available here: http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android-PullToRefresh library, it contains different ready-to-use wraps for GridView, ListView, ScrollView and **WebView**. Please take a look at: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide.

Answer (score 0):

Download Zip from the  following link.Add the library project(library) to both PullToRefreshListFragment & PullToRefreshViewPager as library project  after that add  PullToRefreshListFragment &PullToRefreshViewPager projects to LauncherActivity to run.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

To use webView PullTorefresh in your project Activity, Your Project-> properties->android->add the library.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can override `overScrollBy()` method and obtain `deltaY` at a given `scrollY` value, then call your inner `javascript` method responsible for starting *pull to refresh*.

[Android ListView: get Overscroll distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815868/android-listview-get-overscroll-distance)