# Android ListView: get Overscroll distance

Tags: java, android, listview, mobile

Is there anyway to determine the exact number of pixels that a user has `overscrolled` by in an Android ListView? When the user tries to scroll up past the first list item, and the **overscroll/bounce** animation kicks in, I need to detect the overscroll distance. Basically I'm going to do something in that space, like a fold in animation, similar to the [Clear](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/clear/) app on **iPhone**.

I've tried calling `getScrollY()` and `getTop()` on my ListView, and its items (using `getChildAt(0).getTop`), but everything returns 0. For reference my list items are all the same height.

I've also tried adding an `onScrollListener` to the `listview` and just calculating the difference between the original Y pos on `ACTION_DOWN`, and the Y pos on `ACTION_MOVE`, but it seems that the `listview` scrolls at a slower velocity.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much digging, and even more frustration, the answer seems to be that you can't. What's even more annoying is that I took a look at the Android [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/widget/AbsListView.java?av=f) and can see that the code I need is all nicely hidden away in the AbsListView's inner gubbings. But all is not lost. Seems that you can build your own view using the AbsListView as a guide, and do what you need inside it. It's more longwinded than I wanted, but so be it. I also found a nice [tutorial](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/) on how to build your own view, in which you can do whatever you want.

Edit

I finally have a demo up and running on Github. If you're interested you can find it [here](https://github.com/garinevans/fancylistview). When you pull down from the top a new view will rotate in, if you let go or scroll up the view will rotate out.

Answer (score 3):

What about overriding this method?

[protected boolean overScrollBy (int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#overScrollBy%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

The scrollY will stay 0, but you could accumulate deltaY when isTouchEvent is true to get how far the user overscrolled.

Comment: Hi Bo, that's interesting, I did override that method and originally deemed it useless as scrollY was always coming out as 0 - I'll take a look at the deltaY parameter though if I get a chance; incidentally I've created a custom list view using the links above and have had great success with it, I'm intending on posting it to git and perhaps writing a short blog article which I'll link back to here. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

at first i think i can get overscroll distance at onOverScrolled,
but in onOverScrolled (int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY)

the scrollX either be 0 or the maxOverScrollDistence.

so you can not get Overscroll distance there.

but you can get Overscroll distance at

> protected boolean overScrollBy (int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent)

for example if your scrollview scroll vertically,
then

> if(deltaY+scrollY<0)
>   {overscrollDistance = deltaY+scrollY}